# Include a PHP configuration value in a Perl file

Tags: php, codeigniter, perl

I have a PHP application in **CodeIgniter (v2.x)** which has a configuration file, this has values in a fairly standard PHP format, such as:

```
$config['key1'] = 'value1';
$config['key2'] = 'value2';
```

I'm writing a Perl program to be run on a nightly basis to parse information into a database for the PHP to use/display, can I get the Perl program to read the configuration values from PHP?

I've tried to `PHP::Include module`, but the Perl values generated appears to be blank (using the DEBUG) module. I've also tried the `Config::IniFiles module`, but my source is not configured as an `ini` file.

Thanks

Comment: Consider changing the configuration to a more language independent format, if you need to use it in multiple languages. XML, JSON, YAML, INI, etc.. Or write an adapter PHP program, that Perl can call and which reads the configuration and presents it in a way your Perl program can use it. Or If the configuration is simple enough try to write your own parser in Perl.

Comment: If the format is really "fairly standard", then a simple regex would be able to just grep those settings.

Comment: @stickybit nothing more i can add to your explanation and i converted the whole config array to json format in my answer.

Comment: @mario - XML, JSON, and YAML are all "fairly standard" configuration formats which cannot be parsed by regexes, much less by simple ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its a simple config file like so...

```
    <?php

/**
*
*  service: /www/vhosts/x456/docs/config.php
*  program: community one
*  version: 1.01, 01/01/2009 01:01:01
*
**/

$config                  = array ();

$config['system_admin']  = 1;

$config['system_name']   = 'Community One';

$config['session_name']  = 'community';

$config['system_email']  = '@gmail.com';

$config['system_allow']  = '127.0.0.1';

$config['storage_type']  = 'file';

$config['host_name']     = '';

$config['service_path']  = '/';

$config['system_root']   = 'c:/services/www/vhosts/x456/';

$config['document_root'] = 'c:/services/www/vhosts/x456/docs/';

$config['database_name'] = 'community';

$config['database_host'] = 'localhost';

$config['database_user'] = 'admin';

$config['database_pass'] = '';

$config['database_type'] = 'mysqli';

$config['database_port'] = '3306';

$config['database_salt'] = '*^&$_';

$config['min_timeout']   = 180;

$config['max_timeout']   = 31557600;

$config['ssl_only']      = FALSE;

?>
```

You could use this old script that I have...

```
use strict;

use warnings;

use Data::Dumper qw ( Dumper );

#error log location and name

my $log = 'C:/services/www/log/errors.txt';

# the hash container

my %data;

# the config file processor

sub configFile
{
    # grab the config files location

    my $file = shift;

    # open the config file up

    open ( CONFIG, '<', $file ) or logError ( 0, $file );

    # read the config file, line by line

    while ( my $line = <CONFIG> )
    {
        # lose the eol and any spaces  found >> (^|$) 

        $line = trim ( $line );

        # move to next line if we don't have a $var

        next if $line !~ /^\$/;

        # move to the next line if there is no
        # (key = value) pair

        my $find  = index $line, '=';

        # grab the array & key name(s) + clean them up

        my $name  = rtrim ( substr $line, 0, $find );

        # grab the value + clean it up

        my $value = ltrim ( substr $line, ( $find + 1 ) );

        # final check, skip over $var(s) = array(), []
        # process only $var['key'] = values!

        next if ( my $pos = index $name, '[' ) == -1;

        # set the (hash key) name = $(hash key)

        my $hash  = substr $name, 1,  ( $pos - 1 );

        # set the variables (key) name = $(hash key)[(key)]

        my $key   = substr $name, ( $pos + 2 ), -2;

        # strip ('|'|;) from the variable(s) value

        if ( $value =~ m/^'|^"/ )
        {
            $value = substr $value, 1, -2;
        }
        else
        {
            $value = substr $value, 0, -1;
        }

        # add the varaible to the data hash

        $data{$hash}{$key} = $value;
    }

    # done, close it

    close CONFIG;
}

sub logError ( )
{
    my ( $type, $data ) = @_;

    open ( ERRORS, '>>', $log );

    print ERRORS $type . ", " . $data . "\n";

    close ERRORS;

    exit ( 0 );
}


sub ltrim
{
    my $s = shift;

    $s =~ s/^\s+//;

    return $s
};

sub rtrim
{
    my $s = shift;

    $s =~ s/\s+$//;

    return $s
};

sub trim
{
    my $s = shift;

    $s =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;

    return $s
};


# the php config style file to process

configFile ( 'C:\\services\\www\\config.php' );

# just print the $data hash out so you
# can see what it returns

print Dumper \%data;
```

The result would be....

```
$VAR1 = {
          'config' => {
                        'ssl_only' => 'FALSE',
                        'database_salt' => '*^&$_',
                        'system_allow' => '127.0.0.1',
                        'system_email' => '@gmail.com',
                        'max_timeout' => '31557600',
                        'database_type' => 'mysqli',
                        'database_pass' => '',
                        'storage_type' => 'file',
                        'database_user' => 'admin',
                        'min_timeout' => '180',
                        'system_admin' => '1',
                        'system_name' => 'Community One',
                        'system_root' => 'c:/services/www/vhosts/x456/',
                        'database_host' => 'localhost',
                        'database_port' => '3306',
                        'session_name' => 'community',
                        'service_path' => '/',
                        'database_name' => 'community',
                        'host_name' => '',
                        'document_root' => 'c:/services/www/vhosts/x456/docs/'
                      }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can convert you config array to a language independent format like json:

```
$json = json_encode($this->config->config);
```

Now that you have your config array in json format, you can save it to a file or retrieve it with an ajax request directly from your program or do whatever you wanna do with it.